# Conditionally assign a value to a random subset of a vector

Tags: r

I want to assign a defined value (let's say 1) to a random sample of a subset of a vector that meets certain conditions. I can't seem to make it work.

I have tried this code:

```
a <- c(1:50)
df <- as.data.frame(a)
df$c <- 0 
df$c[sample(x=(df$c[df$a>25]), size = round(NROW(df$c[df$a>25])/5), replace = F)] <- 1
```

I would like just to randomly make some of the `df$c` vector values to be equal to 1, exactly a random sample of one fifth of the values in `df$c` in which value of `df$a` is a is greater than 25 (that would be 5 observations switched to 1).

But so far all of them remain 0 :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way with base R -

```
df$c[sample(which(df$a > 25), sum(df$a > 25)/5)] <- 1
```

Be aware that this will fail if there is only 1 value in `df$a > 25`.

Below approach will not fail for any case but is bit verbose. Feel free to use whatever suits your need the best depending on expected values in `df$a` -

```
df$c[which(df$a > 25)[sample(length(which(df$a > 25)), sum(df$a > 25)/5)]] <- 1
```

Also, note that since, `relace = F`, sample `size = sum(df$a > 25)/5` must be `<= length(which(df$a > 25))`. You can include this condition in your code if you want to make it even more safer.

Also, there will be no change if `sum(df$a > 25)/5 < 1` so you may want to use `size = max(sum(df$a > 25)/5, 1)` if you want at least 1 change.

Here's a nicer version of my first version, thanks to @Frank -

```
df$c <- replace(df$c, sample(w <- which(df$a > 25), length(w)*.2), 1)
```

Comment: Another way: `replace(df$c, sample(w <- which(df$a > 25), length(w)*.2), 1)`

Comment: @Frank Thanks! added to the answer. I guess this one fails too if there is only 1 `df$a > 25`, right? Basically, sampling will happen from `1:which(df$a > 25)` in that case which would be wrong.

Comment: I don't think there's any issue of failure or incorrect results here actually. If you try with `df$a > 49` or `df$a > 100` (1 or 0 length `which` output), `df$c` is unchanged, which I would think is expected, and there is no error. This is true for all the methods shown in the answer.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan You are right. To generalize, in this specific case, there will be no change if `length(which) < 5`. OP will have to clarify that for a more refined answer.

Comment: Thanks you all. The answers work. Indeed you need at least 5 observations to be able to sample at least one if the share sampled is one fifth, but I don't need more refinement :) Cheers!

Comment: By the way, is there a way to set a "seed" to sample so I always get the same actual sample if I repeat the command?

Comment: @JuanC just adding `set.seed(x)` at the top your code should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as the other solution you have but here's another way:

```
df <- data.frame('a' = c(1:50), 'c' = rep(0,50))

df$c[sample(
  # subset to sample
  df$a[df$a > 25], 
  # sample size
  size = round(length(df$a[df$a > 25])/5, 0), 
  # no replacement 
  replace = F)] <- 1
```

Yours didn't work because you sample where `df$c > 25` rather than `df$a`

```
df$c[sample(x=(   df$c   [df$a>25]), size = round(NROW(df$c[df$a>25])/5), replace = F)] <- 1
```

Comment: Oh thanks!! You're right, I had to impose the subsetting condition to the same vector df$a for it to work!